# How to add encode attribute to variables

Tags: python

When I run the code, there is an error of :
attributeerror: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'encode'.
How can I assign the encode attribute to the variable?

Codes are as follows:
for entry in self._caption_entries:

```
        tokens = self._tokenizer.encode(entry["caption"])
        tokens = tokens[: self._max_seq_length - 2]
        tokens = self._tokenizer.add_special_tokens_single_sentence(tokens)
```

I'm still a newcomer to the forum. I don't know how to ask questions correctly. If there's anything wrong, please correct it.

Comment: You don't add it. The problem is that the value of `self._tokenizer` is `None`, not a string. You need to examine the code that sets `self._tokenizer` and figure out why it's not assigning a string as you expect.

Comment: On any site, if you want site guidelines, check their [help] (on SO, look for the question marks: ?⃝). Also (and very importantly), SO is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8949252/90527)